# Redirection of url on specific url

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have some url like https://www.example.com/newsfeed/show in codeigniter and I have to generate some specific url before controller like https://www.example.com/new/newsfeed/show without changes in base url.How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, this question is liable to be put **on hold** as you didn't provide any relevant attempt to solve this question and you need more explanation on your questions, including those which addresses your tags. The negative score indicate **urgent attention is needed** - edit now and reply back!

Answer (score 0):

New url can be obtained by:

```
var newUrl = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + '/new/'+ location.pathname
```

This will give you your desired url

Comment: Thanku Tanmaya.
Suppose I have a button "View Profile" and I have given a href link https://www.example.com/viewprofile/index in CodeIgniter. And  when I click on this link,in url it must show https://www.example.com/new/viewprofile without changes in button href link.